# How can I determine the coordinations of the deepest point of a pit located on a 3D object?

Tags: objects, coordinates, measurement, texture-coordinates

I am trying to find the deepest point of a rough pit located on a rough 3d object. The pit is full of irregular vertices.

[image]
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1muCjhRDHhwo3AnY194BAvkaCpPIdyWhx

I cannot determine which one of them is the lowest. Could you please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of the pit? Can't you just go into front view, and wireframe mode and *see* which vertex is the lowest?

Comment: Thank you @Leander
I can go into front view and see vertices as seen in the screenshot below however I am trying to find the exact lowest point of the surface. I am going to make measurements regarding this point for my scientific article so I need to be very precise. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1muCjhRDHhwo3AnY194BAvkaCpPIdyWhx

Answer (score 1):

**Local minima**

Calculus is full of finding [maxima and minima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) of equations.  Numerical methods , generally iterative, can be employed to find turning points based from  [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Geometric_interpretation) or [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) to name a couple.

Turning points occur where the derivative (tangent) is zero.  Inconveniently the mesh isn't defined as an equation.  For every vertex there is a normal, that is perpendicular to the tangent.

[image]
*Vertex selected in "ding" in icosphere test*

As a simple test case, for each vertex:

- Create an imaginary plane from coordinate and normal.
- For all vertices of neighbouring faces if the distance to plane is greater than or equal to zero then it is "below" all neighbours and considered a local minimum
- The test is looking at all neighbouring verts being above, for a really rough mesh this may need to be relaxed slightly.

Simple edit mode test script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

from mathutils.geometry import distance_point_to_plane as dp2p
context = bpy.context
context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True, False, False)
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.select_flush(True)


for v in bm.verts:
    # define "vertex" plane
    p_no = v.normal
    p_co = v.co
    # neighbouring verts
    nvs = set(nv for f in v.link_faces for nv in f.verts)
    v.select = all(
            dp2p(nv.co,p_co,p_no) <= 0 
            for nv in nvs)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

[image]
*Result of reversal of test. `dp2p(nv.co,p_co,p_no) <= 0` as a useful way to find concavities*

Once a point is selected its local depth (*depth from surface*) could be calculated (estimated) by selecting out from point until distance from plane stops increasing, and choose the max.

As mentioned this is a very simple test. Once a vicinity is known a more robust method like raycasting could be employed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried mesh analysis?

The Sharp analysis:

[image]

And Thickness:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping!